# Xamarin Forms TableView Default Padding

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, tableview

I want to add ViewCell and SwitchCell inside a TableView. I want to know what is the default margin for SwitchCell so I can make the TableView looks beautiful. Can you help me?

```
    <TableView Intent="Form">
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="?, ?, ?, ?">
                        <!-- Something-->
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
                <SwitchCell Text="Something"/>
            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
    </TableView>
```

Comment: it's dependent on your design. try to put 10,5,10,5

Comment: @PratikPatel Okay I will try that, but actually the problem is my switchcell's label is truncated, so I use ViewCell instead, do you have any solution for that?

Comment: You can use Grid instead of ViewCell. may be it's help you. check my ans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Grid instead of ViewCell. Try like this

```
    <TableView Intent="Form">
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection>
                <Grid>
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Padding="?, ?, ?, ?">
                        <!-- Something-->
                    </StackLayout>
                    <SwitchCell Grid.Column="1" Text="Something"/>
                </Grid>                    
            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
    </TableView>
```

Answer (score 1):

In a custom renderer for a view cell on iOS, you get access to the `TableView`. The `TableView` has a `SeparatorInset` value for the inset of the separator, which handily is the same as the margin we require for the view cell.

This seems to work well across all the iPhone emulator images I tried (SE, iPhone XR, iPhone XS) on iOS 12.2.

```
public override UIKit.UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv)
{
    var inset = tv.SeparatorInset.Left;
    var viewCell = (ViewCell) item;

    viewCell.View.Margin = new Thickness(inset, 0, inset, 0);

    return base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
}
```